# Android Studio Dolphin | Pair a new devices over WI-FI

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am using the canary version of Android Studio, Can't connect my device using WI-Fi pairing.

It shows

> **This system does not meet the requirements to support Wi-Fi pairing.
> Please update to the latest version of "platform-tools" using the SDK
> manager.**

[image: Screenshot]

Checking SDK manager : *platform-tools* --*version* `33.0.1` ( *latest* )

I have also enabled adb for wireless debugging in

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Debugger` > `Android Debug Bridge (adb)`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3. It works just fine for me. Why don't you try to use Android Studio Bumblebee instead of Dolphine?

Comment: Dolphin is a beta/canary version, most likely you also have to install the beta version of platform-tools, but the SDK-manager only shows stable versions.